# Sending data from html form to Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating quiz application (mcq type)in which I want to send data from html file to views.py in order to check user's answer by submitted by radio-button. What should I do?
Plz give any example. 
I am very new to Django and html.. 
This is my model.py file.

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.IntegerField(default=1800)
    array = models.CharField(max_length=800,default="1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userid

class Questions(models.Model):
    question=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    op1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    op2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    op3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    op4 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

Comment: Django ModelForms are a big but beautiful topic; you can tie forms to models for validation, cleaning, and manipulation / saving data. Too much for a SO post, but this is a good start - http://www.pydanny.com/core-concepts-django-modelforms.html.

Comment: Can't I do this without forms? bcz I have used only models.py ,urls.py,views.py and html file to develop my application. I have to make lot of changes to use forms.py file. Any comment...

Comment: You COULD, but I don't know why you WOULD. 
Validation in Django is tied to forms. You COULD read request.GET / request.POST for errors, but... I'd suggest you just use forms. Do a couple tutorials and you'll be able to understand just where you can take (major) shortcuts by doing things the Django way